# Switch statement Message.Contains

Tags: c#, exception, if-statement, switch-statement

Is it possible to make a switch statement which checks on a `Message.Contains` statement?

So instead of this:

```
if (ex.Message.Contains("hnummer"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Deze laptop staat al in de lijst");
}
if (ex.Message.Contains("serienummmer"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Dit serienummer staat al in de lijst");
}
if (ex.Message.Contains("olcnummer"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("Dit OLC nummer staat al in de lijst");
}
```

A switch statement?

Comment: Guess no since it would have to be a compile time constant

Comment: You could create a Dictionary of marker-strings and delegates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way would be to use a Dictionary

```
//of course, the "staat al in de lijst" could be a constant, as we like DRY
var messageDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
   {"hnummer", "Deze laptop staat al in de lijst"},
   {"serienummmer", "Dit serienummer staat al in de lijst"}
}
```

then something like that (if you want multiple messagebox for each "successfull" contains test, as your code suggests).

```
foreach (var kvp in messageDictionary) {
      if (ex.Message.Contains(kvp.Key))
      Messagebox.Show(kvp.Value);
      //break; if you wanna stop after first match.
}
```

or if you want to test all "contains" but get only one aggregated message

```
var res = string.Empty;
foreach (var kvp in messageDictionary) {
   if (ex.Message.Contains(kvp.Key))
          res +=kvp.Value;
}
MessageBox.Show(res);
```

or a "don't do that" oneliner way

```
MessageBox.Show(string.Join("\n", messageDictionary.Select(m => ex.Message.Contains(m.Key) ? m.Value : string.Empty)));
```

Comment: Not if this is a part of some search function... ("contains" method suggests such usage)